# How everything can be access using $this in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in CodeIgniter and just webt through CodeIgniter framework and documentation. But I couldn't understand how everything can be access using keywork $this only. I mean If I'm loading library or helper in constructor, have tou use this->load->library();

Where can I find class/function named "load" and how it is accessible using "$this".

Just want to understand how this MVC framework.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

Answer (score 0):

You use the variable $this to access the class's method. For exemple:

```
class foo {

public function hello(){
    print "hello";
}

public function using_hello()
{
    $this->hello();
}
}
```

In another words, when you use $this->load->library, probably there is a method called load, and inside there are another methods, like library.

I think, its not so simple like this, but this is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

All controllers extend the main CI_Controller, so calling something like `$this->load` means accessing the parent method `load()` inside the parent class CI_Controller.

`$this->ci` works because with `$this->ci = &get_instance()` you're calling a reference to the main controller class...again. If you look in the bootstrap file (IIRC. Or the codeigniter.php file) there's the function `get_instance()`, which does nothing but return (by reference) the instance of the CI_Controller class.

So, basically, calling `$this->ci->load` and $this->load are the same exact thing, only that the first is unnecessary within a Controller/Model/View because the system is already doing that in the parent class (through the method load).

If you have a look at libraries, for ex., you'll see instead that using `$this->ci->method()` is necessary, because you need to have available all the methods of the CI_Controller, which is a kind of "super class" that drives the whole framework.

Have a look at the loader class and the CodeIgniter class to grasp how CI internally works. Please see this link for more : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the `index.php` file loads `/system/core/CodeIgniter.php`. It sets a few variables, like `$EXT`, `$BM`, `$OUT` and so on.

Later, when a request is made, this is what resides in `/system/core/Controller.php`:

```
class CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        (...)

        // Assign all the class objects that were instantiated by the
        // bootstrap file (CodeIgniter.php) to local class variables
        // so that CI can run as one big super object.
        foreach (is_loaded() as $var => $class)
        {
            $this->$var =& load_class($class);
        }

        (...)
    }
```

This means that the variables initialized in `CodeIgniter.php` are loaded inside the controller (e.g. `$DB` becomes `$this->db` and so on), so that you can use most of the things only by writing `$this->something`.